# Why do I not get the value from length in this Prolog Query?

Tags: list, prolog

I have something like this in my .pl file:

```
...
path_length(A, B, length(L, size)) :-
    path_record(A, B, L).
...
```

And when i do:

```
path_length(a,g,X)
```

I get:

```
X = length([a,b,c,d,f,g],size)
```

But what I want the query to return is:

```
X = 6
```

What am I doing wrong? I am obviously new to Prolog so sorry if this question is low level and the answer is obvious to some.

I can add more info if required for helping out. (Can't add the whole .pl though, sorry) Let me know! :)

Any help appreciated! :) Ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path_length(A, B, Size) :-
    path_record(A, B, L),
    length(L, Size).
```

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks @CapelliC for quick and perfect assistance! :)